# Python: strings received with raw_input behave strange

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

During my work on a remote controlled RC-car I've been faced with a problem: the car is controlled with a simple CLI, and sometimes when I type in correct commands, the CLI says they're incorrect, even if they aren't.

Below you see the code which causes the whole problem. Can somebody explain this behaviour and in best case give a fix?

```
command = raw_input("?")
   while command != "quit":
    if command == "forwards":
        forwards()
        command = 0
        command = raw_input("?")
    if command == "backwards":
        backwards()
        command = 0
        command = raw_input("?")
    if command == "left forwards":
        leftforwards()
        command = 0
        command = raw_input("?")
    if command == "right forwards":
        rightforwards()
        command = 0
        command = raw_input("?")
    if command == "right backwards":
        rightbackwards()
        command = 0
        command = raw_input("?")
    if command == "left backwards":
        leftbackwards()
        command = 0
        command = raw_input("?")
    if command == "selftest":
        selftest()
        command = 0
        command = raw_input("?")
    if command == "help":
        help()
        command = 0
        command = raw_input("?")
    if command == "distance":
        navix()
        print navix_distance
        command = 0
        command = raw_input("?")
    else:
        print("Invalid input, try again")
        command = 0
        command = raw_input("?")
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we simplify the structure of your code, it'll end up looking roughly like this:

```
command = raw_input('?')
while command != 'quit':
    if command == 'forwards': 
        forwards()
    if command == 'backwards':
        backwards()

    # ...snip...

    if command == "distance":
        navix()
    else:
        print('invalid input')
```

Now, say that you type in `forwards` when asked for input. Well, then you hit the first if statement, which is true, and execute the correct command.

But then, what happens when you hit the very last if/else statement? Well, `command` is not equal to `distance`, so you hit the else case -- the "invalid input" case.

To fix this, you should convert all of your if statements into if/elif/else statements -- restructure your code so that once one command matches, you skip all the rest.

There's also a bunch of repetition in your code. There are a wide varieties of strategies for handling this, but at minimum, you should consolidate the code to ask for user input instead of repeating it in each clause:

```
command = raw_input('?')
while command != 'quit':
    if command == 'forward':
        forward()
    elif command == 'backwards':
        backwards()
    # ...snip...
    elif command == 'distance':
        navix()
    else:
        print('invalid command')

    command = raw_input('?')
```

You also don't have to zero out the command before setting it to a new value, since it'll be overridden anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Use elif instead of if. In you current code each of the if blocks is executed. The else block belongs to only the last if statement. And if the last one fails, The else block is executed. So, even if the input is "forwards", There are two pieces that execute-

- `if command=="forwards":`   block
- The only else block (since the last `if` is false)

So, you get the `"Invalid input, try again"` message.

Use elif instead of each if (except the first of course) so that only a single block is executed.